# RxSearchView observing textChanges and Events at the same time

Tags: android, rx-java, searchview, rx-binding

I am using `RxSearchView` to query the text changes in a form of "Search as you type"

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
```

but I would like to also catch when the user submits the search, so then I have to use

`RxSearchView.queryTextChangeEvents(searchView)` or `searchView.setOnQueryTextListener`

When I use any of these last 2, it looks like they are cancelling the first `RxSearchView.queryTextChanges`, looks like that there can only be 1 observable attached to SearchView.

How can I observe both events at the same time?

Here is the full code

```
private void setupSearch() {
        RxSearchView.queryTextChangeEvents(searchView)
                .skip(1)
                .throttleLast(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .onBackpressureLatest()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .filter(new Func1<SearchViewQueryTextEvent, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(SearchViewQueryTextEvent searchViewQueryTextEvent) {
                        final boolean empty = TextUtils.isEmpty(searchViewQueryTextEvent.queryText());
                        if (empty) {
                            //Dont show anything  clear adapter
                        }
                        return !empty;
                    }
                }).subscribe(new Subscriber<SearchViewQueryTextEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void onNext(SearchViewQueryTextEvent searchViewQueryTextEvent) {
                String searchTerm = searchViewQueryTextEvent.queryText().toString();
                if (searchViewQueryTextEvent.isSubmitted()) {
                    submitFullSearch(searchTerm);
                } else {
                    submitRecommendationsSearch(searchTerm);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }


        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one observable since it overwrites the view's listener, but you can use `RxSearchView.queryTextChangeEvents(searchView)` to monitor both types of events.  It gives a stream of [`SearchViewQueryTextEvent`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding-appcompat-v7/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding/support/v7/widget/SearchViewQueryTextEvent.java) events.  For each event, you can check `isSubmitted()` to determine if it is a submission or a change event and fetch the current text with `queryText()`.

Here is how could use `ConnectableObservable` to get the events into two streams to filter separately --

```
private void setupSearch() {
    ConnectableObservable<SearchViewQueryTextEvent>  searchObs = RxSearchView.queryTextChangeEvents(searchView).publish();
    searchObs.skip(1)
            .throttleLast(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .onBackpressureLatest()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .filter(new Func1<SearchViewQueryTextEvent, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(SearchViewQueryTextEvent searchViewQueryTextEvent) {
                    final boolean empty = TextUtils.isEmpty(searchViewQueryTextEvent.queryText());
                    if (empty) {
                        //Dont show anything  clear adapter
                    }
                    return !empty;
                }
            }).subscribe(new Subscriber<SearchViewQueryTextEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void onNext(SearchViewQueryTextEvent searchViewQueryTextEvent) {
            String searchTerm = searchViewQueryTextEvent.queryText().toString();
            if (!searchViewQueryTextEvent.isSubmitted()) {
                submitRecommendationsSearch(searchTerm);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
        }
    });

    searchObs.subscribe(new Subscriber<SearchViewQueryTextEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(SearchViewQueryTextEvent searchViewQueryTextEvent) {
            if (searchViewQueryTextEvent.isSubmitted()) {
                submitFullSearch(searchTerm);
            }
        }
    });

    Subscription searchSub = searchObs.connect();
```

Comment: I just updated the answer with the full code but the thing is that the debounce and throttleLast will also affect the search with the submit and I was hoping to separate them

Comment: there is also this example https://github.com/kmdupr33/iosched/blob/feature/rxjava_rewrite/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/SearchActivity.java  but I can't find the DelegatingOnQueryTextListener.java class to test it

Comment: @JavierVargas If you need multiple subscriptions, take a look at `ConnectableObservable`s (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Connectable-Observable-Operators).  You can then filter each stream separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have posted another question that is related to this if you have a chance to take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40962300/rx-searchview-needs-to-cancel-on-going-request-with-less-priority